# What is the cause for the outage

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

I have a breaker outside the house next to the meter. Quite often, almost twice a week, it trips and I have to go outside to reset it. The breaker in the house, located in the garage, doesn’t trip. How do I prevent this? What is the cause?

Comment: You need to add a bunch more information.  Pictures of the breaker would help.  What does it switch?  What is the rating of the breaker?  What loads are on it at the time it trips?  Like is it feeding the whole house and you have an oven a dryer and a power tool running when it trips?  Is it properly weatherproofed for its location?

Comment: Can you post the amp rating of the breaker in question, as well as photos of the panel inside the house, and how many square feet the house is?

Comment: **More likely** - too much power draw for the size of the breaker/service. **Much less likely** - defective breaker. What part of the world are you in, what size is the breaker outside, what electrical appliances does hour house have - [edit] to include those details, and ideally some pictures.